# Can I use more + faster SODIMM with old laptop now I've switched from Celeron to Pentium 4?

Tags: laptop, processor, memory

I have an ancient laptop that officially maxes out at 384MiB; that's 128MiB soldered on the mobo, and a 256MiB SO-DIMM. I've swapped the CPU from a 1.5GHz Intel Celeron, with a 2.4GHz Pentium 4 (it boots!) and I *believe* that by replacing the CPU, the machine might allow more RAM, and I'm also hoping that it might allow for faster RAM?

NOTE: The Pentium 4 did previously run at 2.4GHz (in an Intel desktop MOBO), and `lshw` shows it as `product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz`, however it appears to be running at 1.8GHz... which is probably a good thing both in terms of power and thermals. It appears to be running fine (on mains power anyway) and is stable.

Obviously, it's horrendously slow and the P4 probably won't help much. But if I could install 1GiB RAM, then it might be vaguely usable.

Attached are photos of the original 1.5GHz Celeron, the replacement 2.4GHz Pentium 4 (I can't read the label but `lshw` says it's `version: 15.2.7`), and the existing 256MiB SO-DIMM.
Yes, the P4 has a heat-spreader on it which makes fitting the heatsink + fan... somewhat challenging... but that's fine!

[image: Intel Celeron]
[image: Intel Pentium 4]
[image: SO-DIMM]

**Update 2024-02-12:**
The 1GB RAM I ordered arrived today. I installed it and... the doesn't seem to work. Photo of the new ram anyway:

[image]

Comment: Memory Limit is a function of the CPU and the motherboard, so probably no.  If you have spare money, you can try larger ram.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RohitGupta! I've decided to take a punt and order this[1] 1GB SO-DIMM.

[1] https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/374824018878?hash=item574540a3be:g:p~kAAOSwLDdkuOmV

Comment: I'm basing the decision in part on this laptop having a SiS 650 chipset and according to this[1] website, it should support 1GB fine... but I'll post back when it arrives (eBay says 14th Feb). If that works, then I'll switch the HDD for an IDE/SD-card storage solution (it's cheapest).

[1] http://www.yjfy.com/M/Matsonic/mainboard/MS9317E.htm

Comment: If this CPU & motherboard are old enough to have the memory controller on the motherboard instead of in the CPU it will mean the motherboard has its own "baked-in" limitations for memory regardless of the CPU. Rohit Gputa's comment remains true for old boards like that; However a newer CPU & Mobo would rely on the CPU alone to determine memory support because the CPU has the memory controller in it.

Comment: Honestly... I've no idea, but my initial Googling pulled up this thread[1] that does suggest it _may_ allow for more memory than the 384MB officially supported, and really, I've ordered 1GB because anything less makes the machine practically useless these days.
[1] https://forums.overclockers.co.uk/threads/upgrading-and-old-laptop.18340244/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you specified exactly what model of laptop that you have, but with what i'm assuming to be your model is a 2002 Dell Inspiron laptop 2600/2650 which in this case the max amount of memory it can handle is 512mb and if there is only one slot then 384mb will probably be the limit unless you can try and use a 512mb stick and see what happens but to be honest I don't see it being worth the headache. It's a 20 year old laptop you can only expect it to be anything but fast, you could use it as a retro gaming machine or even run MS-DOS and learn some legacy stuff if that interests you at all.

TLDR: No you can't upgrade to 1gb of ram due to the limitations of the hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; not sure why I didn't state the make/model, but you're right I should have! FYI it's a Packard Bell iGo 4450 (aka NEC Versa e400).

The 1GB memory arrived today and... yeah, you're right it doesn't work!! :O

Specifically, the BIOS doesn't seem to recognise the memory. And since it only has one memory slot, with 128MB soldered on the mobo, you're probably also right about the 384MB limit.

I knew it was a fairly pointless experiment in that it was still a very old and slow computer, but the 1GB RAM was fairly cheap so, that's that.

Comment: If the memory upgrade had worked, then I would've replace the HDD with an IDE/SD-card device (cheaper than the admittedly more robust looking IDE to M.2 devices), but I think I'll call it a day on trying to revive this thing.

Thanks again for your comments though - I do appreciate it!! :D

Comment: @PeterRyan Sorry for the late reply, but thanks for the follow up even though I assumed it wouldn't it feels better to get confirmation not that I doubt myself but sometime things work without any explanation lol, tech can be weird. Just out of curiosity though, just because the bios doesn't recognize it doesn't mean that it wasn't being utilized. Did you boot into an OS and try reading the memory from there? The bios may not read it because it could be a way out of date bios for that specific SODIMM